# C# Visual Studio DataTable Debugger Visualizer with Row Numbers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatable, debuggervisualizer

The inbuilt Visual Studio DataTable Debugger Visualizer does not display the row numbers, and does not support copying to clipboard and pasting to Excel. Is there any other Visualizer available that supports these features? I need to examine the values in specific rows in a large DataTable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just writing a class that pulls the line from the data table to a temp string that you can look at in the debugger.

From there it would be really easy to just write the file as a csv that you can open in excel.